# Problem in including 3D pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, overleaf

I am including a few 3D pgfplots in my book, but when I am recompiling, it is frequently giving timeout errors.

A manual warns about this problem with 3D pgfplot. Is it a real problem? Does anyone have any experience with the use of 3D pgfplots in a book?

Comment: if you get timeout you are presumably using overleaf or similar service as tex run locally has no time limits. So you could run locally, or process each plot as separate documents and include the pdf into your main document

Comment: No, I was forced to add some known tag. I have tried to use timeout, pgfplot but system was not allowing.

Comment: I used pgfplots also overleaf, which I assume you are using?